# How can I get the script link for fontawesome.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use

This is the link where I need to get the script code from, but the link from here is not working.

The link to put in my HTML:

```html
<script defer src="/your-path-to-fontawesome/js/all.js"></script> <!--load all styles -->
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a CDN.
You can simply google for packageName CDN.

I use bootstrap CDN for my projects, I would add this in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

But the CDN link might be different (e.g. you might want to use a different version of the package) so I suggest you to search it on the internet.